# Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. Token is expired

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-webjobs, azure-managed-identity

I have a webjob hosted within Azure which is scheduled to run continuous mode type. In this webjob I have some database operations which are managed using EntityFrameworkCore. I am also using userassigned ManagedIdentity to get the token and pass it to the AccessToken property of the connection. The token lifetime of the userassigned ManagedIdentity is 24 hours. For the first time the webjob runs successfully without any issues, but on the subsequent iterations post 24 hours it breaks , since the token by that time has expired.

**Program.cs**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true).AddEnvironmentVariables();
    IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
    IHost host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureWebJobs(webJobConfiguration =>
    {
        webJobConfiguration.AddAzureStorage();
        webJobConfiguration.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        webJobConfiguration.AddTimers();
    }).ConfigureServices(serviceCollection =>
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<ImportFunctions>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(new ConfigManager(configuration));
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(IDBAuthTokenService), typeof(AzureSqlAuthTokenService));
        serviceCollection.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(GetConnectionString()));
    }).Build();
    using (host)
    {
        host.Run();
    }

    string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string connection = configuration["connectionString"];
        bool readFromKeyVault = bool.Parse(configuration["ReadFromKeyVault"] ?? "false");
        if (readFromKeyVault)
        {
            connection = GetKeyVaultClient().GetSecretValue("appconnectionstring");
        }

        return connection;
    }

    KeyVaultAccessClient GetKeyVaultClient()
    {
        string keyVaultURL = configuration["KeyVaultURL"];
        string userAssignedClientId = configuration["MsiConfiguration:UserAssignedClientId"];
        return new KeyVaultAccessClient(keyVaultURL, userAssignedClientId);
    }
}
```

**IDBAuthTokenService.cs**

```
public interface IDBAuthTokenService
{
    Task<string> GetTokenAsync();
}
```

**AzureSqlAuthTokenService.cs**

```
public class AzureSqlAuthTokenService : IDBAuthTokenService
{
    public AzureSqlAuthTokenService()
    {
    }

    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions{ManagedIdentityClientId = ConfigManager.Get("UserAssignedClientId")});
        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[]{ConfigManager.Get("AzureSQLResourceId")});
        var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, default);
        return token.Token;
    }
}
```

**AppDbContext.cs**

```
public partial class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext()
    {
    }

    public AppDbContext(IDBAuthTokenService tokenService, DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        var connection = this.Database.GetDbConnection() as SqlConnection;
        connection.AccessToken = tokenService.GetTokenAsync().Result;
    }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

In this implementation I tried to leverage polly nuget package to implement the retry logic as mentioned below:

**ImportFunctions.cs**

```
public class ImportFunctions
{
    private IEmailEID _emailEID;
    private IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IDBAuthTokenService _tokenService;
    private AsyncRetryPolicy retryPolicy;
    public ImportFunctions(IEmailEID emailEID, IConfiguration config, IDBAuthTokenService tokenService)
    {
        _emailEID = emailEID;
        _config = config;
        _tokenService = tokenService;
#region RetryDetails
        int MAX_RETRIES = 3;
        retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>(ex => ex.Message.Trim().Length > 0).WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: MAX_RETRIES, sleepDurationProvider: (attemptCount) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(attemptCount * 2), onRetry: (exception, sleepDuration, attemptNumber, context) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception details: {exception.Message}");
            ReInitializeAppDbContext();
        });
#endregion
    }

    public void DailyTrigger([TimerTrigger(typeof(DailyJobSchedule))] TimerInfo timerInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!bool.Parse(_config["disableEmails"]))
            {
                //Code here runs every day                 
                Console.WriteLine("Daily Job triggered at :" + DateTime.Now);
                _emailEID.TestMethod1();
                _emailEID.TestMethod2();
                Console.WriteLine("Daily Job ended at :" + DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception :" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ReInitializeAppDbContext()
    {
        var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>().UseSqlServer(GetConnectionString()).Options;
        using var context = new AppDbContext(_tokenService, contextOptions);
    }
}
```

Any database call that happens after 24 hours fails since the token has expired by that time and in that case I am trying to reintialize the dbcontext with a new token as mentioned in the method : ReInitializeAppDbContext()

But still I see the error : Login failed for user ''. Token is expired for all the executions post 24 hours duration.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Where exactly are you using your `retryPolicy`? I can only see that the policy is defined but I don't see any `ExecuteAsync` call.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking advantage of the recent versions of the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet package which takes care of the token acquisition/caching/renewal process.

See this blog post I wrote about it: https://mderriey.com/2021/07/23/new-easy-way-to-use-aad-auth-with-azure-sql/

If you cannot use it or want to get the token yourself, I’d suggest adding logging to the code to ensure that then token renewal process does happen as you expect it to.

Before the newer versions of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient came along, I had success using code from this blog post: https://mderriey.com/2020/09/12/resolve-ef-core-interceptors-with-dependency-injection/

Comment: Thanks @Mickaël Derriey for your response. In my case I am using EF Core 2.2.6 and chances of  upgrading it to latest version are less due to lot of new enhancements request. Also in this case I am getting issues in case of Azure Webjob which runs in continuous mode only. I did validated with other Azure Webjobs which runs on demand based on cron express where everything works as expected. Any thoughts and suggestions on how to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: My gut feel says that it’s a lifetime issue, in other words only a single instance of your DbContext is used throughout the lifetime of the application. The `ReInitializeAppDbContext` doesn’t seem to do anything, it’s creating a new DbContext instance that is never used. Or at least that’s what I get from the code shown in the original question. Also, which service is using the DbContext in ImportFunctions?

Comment: Thanks @Mickaël Derriey for your response. In this case DbContext is inherited by AppDbContext which is injected into the constructor of the service class which contains methods:  TestMethod1() and TestMethod2().  Can you suggest anyway how to resolve this issue

Comment: Is the service class registered as a singleton by any chance?

Comment: Yes @@Mickaël Derriey you are spot on. In short both AppDbContext and the Serviceclass are registered as Singleton

Comment: I think this is where the problem is. By default, EF DbContexts are registered as scoped. Because your service class is a singleton, it means it “holds” a single instance of your DbContext, which means the token to access Azure SQL is never updated. This is known as a captive dependency issue, see https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/. Change the service class to be scoped or transient and your problem should go away. Let me know how you go and I’ll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mickaël Derriey for your response. I did made the changes and validated it and found still not working. I am still seeing the error.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is maybe your token acquisition process is buggy and always returns the same token, even when it's not valid anymore. I strongly suggest to add logging to your application to make sure that several instances of your DbContext are being created, that the token you use is not always the same, etc... Without having a look at the code, it's only a guess as to what is not working as expected, and there's a lot that can go wrong. I'll suggest again to use recent versions of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient so you can focus on feature work and not token-related issues.

Comment: Thanks @Mickaël Derriey for the response. The code to fetch the token is mentioned in the question above : AzureSqlAuthTokenService.cs

Comment: Looks right to me. Did you confirm a new instance of your DbContext is created every time the timer triggers? Did you confirm a new token is acquired every time? You can add logs to confirm this.